# Changing parameters for include files with CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to set up a toolchain for CMake and have made some progress (it's getting the right compiler and all), but I've run into a problem with the -I (include directories directive).

The compiler I'm using doesn't understand -I, it understands -i.   What I don't understand is where to change this so that CMake builds the makefile with the -i rather than the -I.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited

Comment: What compiler are you using?  CMake usually knows about these details and changes these things for you under the hood.

Comment: I'm using a trial of the Cosmic compiler and using the Unix Makefile generator (because I assume that would be the closest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in your CMakeLists.txt file, you should add the following line:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_FLAG_C "-i")
```

This will change your include flag from the default of `-I` to `-i`.  Do  `CMAKE_INCLUDE_FLAG_CXX` for C++.

I say this with the caveat that you might want to wrap this in a `if` that only does this for the Cosmic compiler.

---

CMake sets this to `-I` by default in the file `CMakeGenericSystem.cmake`... search your cmake install dir this file and you will see the CMake defaults for several settings inside.  If a compiler has to modify this, it will be in the `Compiler` folder in the same dir as `CMakeGenericSystem.cmake`.  I'm willing to bet that there is nothing implemented in the `Compiler` folder for the Cosmic compiler.

Comment: That did the trick; and the rest of the information you provided is a bonus as I have to figure out what other flags are being passed to the compiler that it doesn't understand.